# Finding bugs in C code

Tags: c, linux, perl, segmentation-fault

UPDATE: Indeed, relying on some program's segfault is a mistake. But I appreciate and learned a lot from the answers I've received here.

segfault.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


/**
  *
  * This binary receives 2 numbers, an L and an R
  *
  * It will intentionally hit Segmentation Fault(actually SIGSEGV) whenever 30 is in the interval [L,R]
  *
  * It will be used to test the binary search segfault finder
  *
  */
int main(int argc, int **argv) {
  char exists;
  char *Q[3000];
  int i;
  int L = atoi((char*)argv[1]);
  int R = atoi((char*)argv[2]);

  printf("L=%d R=%d",L,R);
  /*exit(0);*/
  for(i=0;i<3000;i++)
    Q[i] = &exists;

  Q[30] = NULL; // <==== I want to cause a SIGSEGV through this !

  for(i=L;i<=R;i++) {
    int T = *Q[i]; // <== will segfault when i == 30 because I said so :)
  };
};
```

automate.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;



my $segfaulting_file = "s";
my $L = 0;
my $R = 7266786; #`cat $segfaulting_file | wc -l`;
my $M;
my $binary = "./filter";

while ($L < $R) {
  $M     = int(($L+$R)/2);
  # head argument for right side
  my $HL = $M;
  # tail argument for right side
  my $TL = $M-$L;
  # head argument for left  side
  my $HR = $R;
  # tail argument for left  side
  my $TR = $R-$M;

  print "M=$M L=$L R=$R\n";
  my $go_left ;
  my $go_right;
  my $cmd_R = "cat $segfaulting_file | head -$HR | tail -$TR | $binary > /dev/null;";
  my $cmd_L = "cat $segfaulting_file | head -$HL | tail -$TL | $binary > /dev/null;";

  print "\nRunning $cmd_R\n";
  `$cmd_R`;
  #`./a.out $M $R`;
  print "RETVAL=$?\n";
  $go_right = ($? > 30000); # right side caused SEGFAULT
  `rm core`;
  print "\nRunning $cmd_L\n";
  `$cmd_L`;
  print "RETVAL=$?\n";
  #`./a.out $L $M`;
  $go_left  = ($? > 30000); # left  side caused SEGFAULT
  `rm core`;

  if(  $L == $R ) {
    last;
  }elsif ( $go_left  ) {
    print "GO left  L=$L R=$R\n";
    $R = $M  ;
  }elsif ( $go_right ) {
    print "GO right L=$L R=$R\n";
    $L = $M+1;
  };
};


# the loop stopped because $L==$R==$M , so we just print out $M
print "Segfault caused by line $M\n";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most reliable way of detecting a seg fault is likely to be using `fork`, `exec`, and `wait`.  You fork the Perl script; the child executes the binary.  The parent collects the exit status from the binary.  There are two parts to the exit status — the value that the child exited with if it exited under control, or the signal that it received if it died from a signal.  You'd simply check whether the signal component was zero or not; if not zero, assume it was a seg fault (though you can validate its number if you wish).  The remaining trick is getting the data for the binary to read available on standard input.  You can have the child launch a pipeline that it reads from and duplicate the pipe to standard input and then close the pipe.  More fiddly than truly difficult.

---

#### Outline Perl Code

I needed a program that crashes, so I created a Perl script `crash_after_reading`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use POSIX;

$| = 1;
print "." while (<>);
print "\n";
abort;
```

Then, the simulator for your Perl script looks like this (`forkwait.pl`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX;

my $pipeline = "cat /etc/group";
my $pid;

die "$!" if (($pid = fork) < 0);

if ($pid == 0)
{
    # Child
    open STDIN, "-|", $pipeline or die "open";
    exec "crash_after_reading";
    die "failed to exec crash_after_reading";
}

my $corpse = waitpid($pid, 0);
printf "PID = %d; status = 0x%.4X\n", $corpse, $?;
```

#### Example output

```
..................................................................................
PID = 92413; status = 0x0006
```

The low-order 8 bits are non-zero, so the child program crashed with signal 6 (SIGABRT).  If the low-order 8 bits were all zero, the child program exited successfully with the status in the high-order 8 bits.

You'll need to adapt this to your code, if you decide to use it at all.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation. Could you post a small example please ? Thank you

Comment: I recommend adopting the approach by `lxop`.  It'll likely be easier.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking Z in order to solve Y in order to solve X... *Stop!* Go back to X. You don't need the log line to work out why it segfaulted. You need the *source code line* that it segfaulted on to work out why it segfaulted, which I presume you know how to get. Work back from that line, following any branches that it may have taken and strategically placing `assert()`ions to determine where the faulty input comes from. Separate repetitive code into functions for reuse as you continue to "iron out the bugs", and you'll be refactoring your code for modularity and stability at the same time.

*edit:* If you really want to continue along these lines, you don't need a perl script. All you need is a counter within your code to count the lines as you parse them, and the help of [signal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/signal.html). When running the following code, [ideone](http://ideone.com/Q3IoTn) doesn't segfault until count is 65535. Hopefully you can see how silly relying upon segfaults for buffer overflows is...

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <limits.h>

void segfault_handler(int sig);

int counter = 0;

int main(void) {
    int *fubar = malloc(0); // allocate ZERO bytes!

    assert(signal(SIGSEGV, segfault_handler) != SIG_ERR);
    assert(signal(SIGILL, segfault_handler) != SIG_ERR);
    assert(signal(SIGFPE, segfault_handler) != SIG_ERR);

    for (;;) {
        printf("Assigning to fubar[%d]\n", counter);
        fubar[counter] = INT_MIN;
        counter = counter * 2 + 1;
    }
}

void segfault_handler(int sig) {
    /* NOTE: Using printf inside a signal handler is also undefined behaviour */
    printf("Fault when counter is %d\n", counter);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: This is also known as an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).  There's some justice to the suggestion that you're asking about an XY Problem.

Comment: You're relying too much upon the fact that undefined behaviour *may* cause segmentation violations; It may not cause segmentation violations, either. This isn't a reliable way to detect errors in C.

Comment: @average That term is neither misused or abused in this case. Rather than asking for advice to "actually solve the problem", you're asking for advice to solve a problem that detects the problem; You're asking for advice reinventing the wheel? Ask yourself this: How do other projects hook SIGSEGV and dump error messages? I'll put the answer in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can edit the source of the filtering program, why not just edit it to write each log file line out to another file before processing it.  Then after the segfault, look at the new file to see what line was being processed at the time.  That will also be faster than your binary search, which will need to process exactly N-1 lines every time, versus this approach which will process on average N/2 lines (depending on the location of the offending line), where there are N lines in the log file.

Comment: +1 for alternative :) The binary search is quite fast. It finishes up a 500MB .gz file in around 3-4 minutes. Yes, I can write the output on disk so I don't have to do more `| head ` and `| tail`. Yes, I can print the lines and see exactly when it segfaulted. That's a good idea also, probably much better than mine.

Comment: I think there is something to this approach. The problem is that it's printing a lot of lines, so I have to wait a lot of time. But even with that, it may still be faster than what I do with the binary search.

Comment: @average You could probably speed it up by simply writing a dot each time before processing a line, then counting the number of dots written (use `wc` or whatever), which will give the line number in the log file.  Writing fewer characters is probably faster.